# Can I coredump a process that is blocking on disk activity (preferably without killing it)?

Tags: linux, cpu-registers, coredump

I want to dump the core of a running process that is, according to `/proc/<pid>/status`, currently blocking on disk activity. Actually, it is busy doing work on the GPU (should be 4 hours of work, but it has taken significantly longer now). I would like to know how much of the process's work has been done, so it'd be good to be able to dump the process's memory. However, as far as I know, "blocking on disk activity" means that it's not possible to interrupt the process in any way, and coredumping a process e.g. using gdb requires interrupting and temporarily stopping the process in order to attach via ptrace, right?

I know that I could just read `/proc/<pid>/{maps,mem}` as root to get the (maybe inconsistent) memory state, but I don't know any way to get hold of the process's userspace CPU register values... they stay the same while the process is inside the kernel, right?

Comment: you can add print of the registers every half an hour in your source code....

Comment: Of course, I'd be much more happy about a ready-made solution than about having to roll my own coredump-maker. :(

Comment: @0x90 right, but I'd like to be able to do this to an already-running program because I don't want to lose ~9h of computed data by force-rebooting or to wait an unknown amount of time for this thing to complete (if it isn't stuck somewhere). also, "every half an hour" wouldn't do it – you'd have to always do it before entering a method that could (or will) block on "disk IO" for an extended amount of time

Answer (score 3):

You can probably run `gcore` on your program. It's basically a wrapper around GDB that attaches, uses the `gcore` command, and detaches again.

This might interrupt your IO (as if it received a signal, which it will), but your program can likely restart it if written correctly (and this may occur in any case, due to default handling).

Comment: As a side note, I just tried this with a simple hello world type program. a call to `read()` resumed automatically.

Comment: Cool! Can you post the source in your answer?

Comment: @Jessemon: For the hello world? It's basically `char c; printf("Hi!\n"); read(0, &c, 1);` As I said, nothing clever.

Comment: This won't work in my case, I already tried gcore. The process is in a noninterruptable sleep.

Comment: @thejh: Ack, In that case, AFAIK, there's no way to do this. GDB would want to stop the process, which will have to wait until the sleep completes. (As an aside, it's generally a bad idea to have the kernel put user tasks in uninterruptable sleep, but I expect there's not much you can do about it.)